# insert array into location.href

Tags: javascript, onclick, location, href, setattribute

I have a program that places input buttons on a form. When a user clicks on the button the onclick attribute uses location.href to direct it to a link.

```
elementButton_1.setAttribute("onclick", "self.location.href='http://google.com'; return false");
```

I am trying to store the links in an array.
How can i insert an array into the location call?

Example:

```
locationArray = new Array();
locationArray[0] = "http://google.com";

elementButton_1.setAttribute("onclick", "self.location.href=locationArray[0]; return false");
```

Comment: You example works, because the second parameter to setAttribute will be evaluated as JS code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand but I think you want:

```
elementButton_1.setAttribute("onclick", "self.location.href='" + locationArray[0] +"'; return false");
```

Comment: I didn't even consider that! Very true. I don't know how to add a comment to your own reply but in general you should not use the constructor form, but use the array literal to instantiate your array. http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2151-when-to-use-the-array-literal-notation-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

**As long as `elementButton_1` is defined, what you posted will work.** However, a much better practice is:

```
locationArray = new Array();
locationArray[0] = "http://google.com";

var elementButton_1 = document.getElementById('mybutton');

// define a click handler for the button
elementButton_1.onclick = function() {
    self.location.href = locationArray[0];
    // ..
}
```

It's better not to define runnable code as a string, for security & maintainability purposes.

- Reference [element.onclick()<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onclick)